# How do I create a stroked line path with precise dimensions in centimeters?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How do I create a stroked line path with precise dimensions? I want a line 19.5 cm long. In the Control bar I can only introduce pixel dimensions.

Comment: Illustrator allows more control when producing non-raster shapes.

Answer (score 2):

The control bar will accept any measurement system you want... by default it uses whatever the preferences/rulers are set to. However, you're free to input something else.

Merely input `19.5cm` in the width field.  Including the `cm` tells Photoshop you want centimeters. -- `in`, `mm`, `pt`.. etc all work.

Answer (score 1):

When the line is straight, you can use the ruler tool. (if it is in pixels you can change units in preferences). You could also count it in pixels if you will check your dpi resolution.